# Workaround for blocked URL shortening services?

Tags: windows-7, blocking, url-shortening

I come across URLs from bit.ly, tinyurl, is.gd, etc. all the time. Unfortunately, these services are blocked by my employer. Is there a tool that unravels these URLs on my machine via some other service so I can get around the block?

I came across a bookmarklet to do this for TinyURLs once, but it'd be nice for something more comprehensive.

Comment: There is an add-on for Firefox to "unshorten" the short URLs and point immediately to their targets but, of course, it has to contact the relevant sites to check what are the targets. So the sites are blocked, it won't work.

Comment: What bookmarklet for TinyURL do you have? For TinyURL, maybe you can ask the system administrators to allow http://tinyurl.com/preview.php ?

Comment: security policies are implemented by your emnployer/IT department for a reason. if you have a problem with that, you should talk to them. not adhearing to or circumventing company security policies may constitute a reason to get fired

Comment: @Molly: I have discussed it with them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

- [LongURL](http://longurl.org/)
- [using a proxy server](http://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+tunnel+with+putty) (if you have access to a Linux/BSD system that's always on)

Comment: LongURL is great. I wish it could silently expand links I click on but it is the closest thing I've found so far so I'll take it. Thanks!

Comment: Note: after using LongURL for a day I got frustrated by frequent errors and freezing. Searching those errors led me to LongURL-Please--it seems to work well, too! http://www.longurlplease.com/

Comment: LongURL-Please is a massive wall of Japanese text with a single photo of a dog.  It will not help you expand URL's.  Cute dog, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can run a shell, `grep`, and `curl`, you could expand them at the command line and copy the url manually with an alias like:

```
expandurl() { curl -sIL "$1" | grep -i '^Location: ' }
```

(The `curl` arguments mean: silent, only download the html headers, and follow redirects until they stop redirecting.)

Comment: Thanks for a command line solution. Note: this only works if the shortened URL isn't blocked, but it was helpful for me, because I almost always have an SSH connection open to a computer that isn't blocked.